# I am getting net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR when my frontend that is running on AWS s3 bucket with cloudfront try to connect my backend on EC2 server

Tags: nginx, ssl, amazon-cloudfront, mern

I am have MERN stack application, it allow users to upload a pdf file from the frontend, the file is processed by the backend, the backend stores the file url in a mongodb database and then uploads the file to an AWS S3 bucket.

Front end: I am hosting the front end as a static website on a AWS s3 bucket, I am also using Cloudfront to serve my frontend hosted on s3 bucket, the cloudfront distribution uses a SSL certificate issued by AWS certificate manager. I am using Route 53 for DNS, and I have created a record that points my domain name to the cloudfront distribution end point.

Deploying front end: I run npm install and npm run build commands to create a build of my frontend, and then I upload the content of my frontend to the s3 bucket.

Backend: The backend is running on a AWS EC2 instance, it is also running the Mongodb database.

Problem: Now when I use the s3 bucket end point  then I can succesfully upload my pdf files to the AWS S3 bucket.

But when I connect to my site using my domain name that points to the cloudfront endpoint with SSL enabled, I get net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR  error.

I have installed nginx and SSL certificate for my backend from certbot and tried connecting to my backend form the frontend over https protocol

I have attached the frontend code snippet where the error is ocurring, the error screenshot, the nginx conf file for my backend.

Link to the screenshot: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1D9arGHe8Vvigv4o9Ihc95MGI1lfibJRe?usp=sharing

Comment: SSL is added for 443, but from UI you are directly hitting 8800 port, can you try not passing port, with that HTTPS will check on 443 and with that it should work. One more suggestion, see if you are getting API logs in nginx logs ( most likely request is not going to nginx itself - though I might be wrong so just a suggestion for now :) )